# Java/Spring: initMocks a class which got @Value from yml file

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am writing unit tests on a Service class like below :

```
@Component
@Profile({"default", "dev"})
public class MyService {
    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String property;

    private OtherService otherService;

    public void MyMethod() {
        String myVar = otherService.method();

        return String.format("MyVar %s & MyProperty %s", myVar, property);
    }
}
```

My current test class for this test is like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private OtherService otherService;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @BeforeEach() 
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(otherService.method()).thenReturn("a string");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnException() {
        final Exception exception = assertThrows(ApiErrorException.class,
        () -> myService.myMethod(var));

    assertThat(exception).hasMessage("here the message");

    verify(otherService, never()).method();
    }
}
```

With this two classes, I have an `application.yml` & `application-dev.yml` to set `my.property`.
I want to get the property from the application-dev file during my tests execution. 
But, with `@InjectMocks`, property is null. Whereas, using `@Autowired` in place of/with `@InjectMocks`, the property variable is set with the value present in file.

Problem, using Autowired with/in place of InjectMock results in the `otherService` variable being initialized, so no mock is created.

How can I still use Mockito, while having the property variable set with the value in the file?
I saw about `ReflectionTestUtils.setField`, but using it mean having no use of a yml file (which i am not fan).

Have a nice day

---

With the help of @Deadpool, the tests can use the values written in the `application.yml` file. 
But, using `@MockBean` and `@Autowired`, the tests get a behavior I do not understand.

Example:
I test that a method return an Exception, and I verify that others methods are not called after the exception was catch: `verify(otherService, never()).otherMethod();`
Writing this line returns the following error `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked`.

The initial exception is correctly caught, but the test does not seem to acknowledge that no other services must be called.

Answer (score 1):

[@SpringBootTest](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#integration-testing-with-springboottest) is used for integration testing which loads the `ApplicationContext` that will be utilized for test environment

> The @SpringBootTest annotation can be used when we need to bootstrap the entire container. The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext that will be utilized in our tests.

Since you are generating integration environment using `@SpringBootTest` you need to mock the bean using [@MockBea](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans)n annotation

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

   @MockBean
   private OtherService otherService;

   @Autowire
   private MyService myService;

   @BeforeEach
   public void init() {

    when(otherService.method()).thenReturn("a string");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works almost great ^^' The tests using the value from `application.yml` works correctly, but another test fails because of the use of `verify(repository).save(any(MyClass.class));`. I am looking to fix it

Comment: I can't tell without seeing the code and proper error message, you can ask the other question with appropriate information @Baerrow

Comment: I put an example

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your `MyService` class to accept the `OtherService` either via the constructor or via setter. Something like this:

```java
@Component
@Profile({"default", "dev"})
public class MyService {
    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String property;

    private OtherService otherService;

    public MyService(OtherService otherService) {
        this.otherService = otherService
    }

    public void MyMethod() {
        String myVar = otherService.method();

        return String.format("MyVar %s & MyProperty %s", myVar, property);
    }
}
```

And then you do your test like this:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private OtherService otherService;

    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @BeforeEach() 
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(otherService.method()).thenReturn("a string");
    }
}
```